# Align the height of 3 items when they are side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap to display 3 items. When the screen is narrow (eg, in a smartphone), they are displayed one after another vertically. When the screen is large, I want them to be displayed side by side in one row. The 3 items do not have same text, but i want them to ALWAYS have the same height when they are in one row. I use the following code:

```
<section id="apps" class="apps section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="app">
          <div class="content">
            ...
          </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- app -->
      </div><!-- col -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="app">
          <div class="content">
            ...
          </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- app -->
      </div><!-- col -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="app">
          <div class="content">
            ...
          </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- app -->
      </div><!-- col -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.apps .app .content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pucozu/10/edit?html,css,output).

The above CSS allows the 3 items to have the same height when the screen is very large:

[image]

However, when the screen is a little bit narrow, they don't have the same height:

[image]

Does anyone know how to always align them when they are side by side?

Comment: The copy length in the boxes will change? Do you know the max length?

Comment: What is "copy length"? I don't understand your questions...

Comment: Copy is just another way of saying text. And length is how many characters

Comment: I will write the texts myself, so they are not random texts. Let's say the max length is 300 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, here's what you want

Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/ec8Lbuvj/2/**

You are searching for flexbox. I don't use your markup but here's how you should do it. It's time for you to analyze your code. Just put display flex to the parent element.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}

.child {
    width: 30%;
    // don't put min-height. It will be automatic
}
```

Note: This technique doesn't work in IE 8 and lower. Cheers. Hope it helped.

I used media queries because this is how bootstrap work.

Comment: OK... I forgot to mention that I still want to use bootstrap. In other words, in smartphone, the 3 items will be displayed one after another vertically, I want to keep that.

Comment: You can also achieve it without using bootstrap. So, the combination of flex and bootstrap is also good. If you want it. I can code it for you.

Comment: If you could provide an answer of bootstrap+flex, that will be great... thank you...

Comment: Can you possibly add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to parent and `flex: 1; min-width: 300px;` (or whatever) to child? https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ec8Lbuvj/1/ increase pane horizontally to see effect.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen You got it mate. Cheers! That's why I love zurb foundation because they used flex. Bootstrap 4 will be on flexbox too. So, we better watch it.

Comment: @SoftTimur I updated the pen. https://jsfiddle.net/ec8Lbuvj/2/ Look at it.

Comment: So you still think bootstrap grid (ie, `col-**-**`) is not necessary?

Comment: @SoftTimur No. It can't. However if you want to use bootstrap on this. You can use javascript to compare each others height. And just apply the highest it to each box. But it's a waste of time. If you can't hack it using flex. Go with it. I think flex is the future of layouting.

Comment: One difference between bootstrap grid and flex is that, by flex the width of each item is always `width: 30%;`, whereas by bootstrap there are only several possible widths of the items according to the width of the screen. Is it possible to let flex to have this style (ie, only have several possible fixed widths)?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. You just need to declare it in other breakpoints. Take a look at media queries. https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Answer (score 1):

You can either set a fixed height or use jQuery plugin like [jQuery Match Height](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) to make sure that the heights are always the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.0/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if( $(window).width() >= 768px ){ //preventing this from running on mobile device, 768px is bootstrap's breakpoint for col-sm-4
        $('.components-class-name').matchHeight();
    }
</script>
```

But this will make the components same height in mobile mode